# How to process an Android interface definition file with doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I have a collection of Java source files that Doxygen is happily processing. Included in the collection is a set of Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) files, used to specify interfaces. I can't get Doxygen to generate output from these.

I added `*.aidl` to `FILE_PATTERNS`, and I can see that doxygen is reading the files --- there's just no output from the contents. The files are valid Java and have Doxygen commands embedded, just like the Java files that *are* processed.

Does anyone have experience using doxygen to process AIDL files?

Comment: Did you have a look at EXTENSION_MAPPING in the Doxyfile?

Comment: Thanks! I missed that in the Doxyfile. I didn't see it in the Doxywizard interface either. (I'm using 1.8.8 on Windows.)

Comment: I'm seeing it tin the doxywizard, expert tab as13-th item from the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, @albert. I see it now on the `Project` page in the Expert settings. I consider my question answered.

Answer (score 1):

To generate the Docs for AIDL files :

1. GoTo Expert --> Input --> FILE_PATTERNS : add `*.aidl` so that Doxygen recognizes aidl files

[image]

2. GoTo Expert --> Project --> EXTENSION_MAPPING : add `aidl=java` to parse similar as java

[image: Adding EXTENSION_MAPPING]